# Review audit problem - flagged off-topic but was really a duplicate

Tags: bug, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3474702

The question was presented during review as off-topic, but was a very clear duplicate of another question with an excellent answer.  When I went to VTC I was informed that I failed the audit.

It is not appropriate to fail an audit immediately upon clicking the Close button without considering the reason to close.  This has happened to me more than once, and indicates a subtle problem with the design of the audit system: questions that deserve to be closed for reasons different from what the audit system assigns them.

Happened again: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3493769

The question is definitely "Unclear what you're asking" but was picked by the audit engine and marked as Off-topic.  Once again, just clicking "Close" brings up the verbal scolding without a chance to provide a real, valid close reason.

The audit engine behavior is broken, and is embarrassing conscientious users who are working to cope with the ever-increasing close-vote queue.

Comment: duuuupe... but yeah, this _is_ a (known (and neglected)) problem.